# Can't switch sides in bootstrap carousel while loading data dynamically in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, carousel

So I wanted to show a testimonial carousel in my App. I've used some fake data. My problem is I can't switch the sides of the carousel after adding the fake data and mapped through them . Can anyone tell me where am I making the mistake

```
const Testimonials = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Our Client Testimonial</h1>
      <div class="container ">
        <div id="demo" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel">
          {testimonials.map((test) => (
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <p>{test.review}</p> <img src={test.image} />
                  <div id="image-caption">{test.name}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
            {" "}
            <span
              aria-hidden="true"
              class="carousel-control-prev-icon"
            ></span>{" "}
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>{" "}
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
            {" "}
            <span
              aria-hidden="true"
              class="carousel-control-next-icon"
            ></span>{" "}
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Testimonials;
```

Answer (score 0):

Testimonials should be in a state controlled by you.

```
const Testimonials= () => {
  const [testimonials, setTestimonials] = useState([]);
}
```

Or it could be a props that you pass to your component

```
const Testimonials= ({ testimonials }) => {
}
```

So react will render if it changes